# CORS blocking get request in code but directly accessing endpoint returns data

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, cors, webserver

I have an angular front end website that is trying to hit an endpoint on a webserver. At this point the website is in a proof of concept phase. Here's the request:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getData(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200'
    });
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true}); }
```

When I directly paste the endpoint URL into the browser I get an XML response with the data. So what is wrong with the request that it is blocked by CORS when running through my webpage but if I paste the URL in the same browser it returns a result?

Comment: CORS should be set on server side. Please check CORS configuration on the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: @Ivar That is a great answer that helped the situation a lot. In the end though we ended up with a different solution to the issue. While I do still believe there is an issue with our back-end service (That I don't own) we found a band-aid with a browser extension that let us continue on development.

Answer (score 1):

CORS is only used for Cross-Origin requests, hence the name. When you paste the request to the browser, the request is executed from the same origin and CORS is not involved.

But then called from the Angular app, the origin is different and browser executes CORS protocol.
CORS needs to be configured on the endpoint webserver. The header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200'`,along with other CORS headers should be send from the endpoint webserver in the response, while in your example you send it to the endpoint server instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should allow the methods in Cors like this

app.use(cors({
"origin": "*",
methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH']
}));